# expandable (month view)/collapsable(week view) calendar widget for android

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, android, android-calendar

I saw this android calendar widget used in an app called cal and was quite impressed.

I would like to implement a similar one in my app as well. Currently I am using an android calendar framework called caldroid and I am using it as a Fragment and will be invoked on action bar button click and will get collapsed clicking back on the action bar button.

But I would like to do the widget like in the app. Screen shots attached.

I would like to know if you guys are aware of any frameworks that can used to achieve this or any approach or tips on how to code this.

I am bit new and know basics of android. Haven't attempted to create custom widgets yet.

Thanks,
Bala

[image: Collapsed calendar showing only the current week]

[image: expanded calendar showing the entire month]

Comment: nope.. i had to use the normal calendar as a work around

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this library can help you.
https://github.com/blazsolar/android-collapse-calendar-view

Comment: wow thanks a lot :) looks like a new one, I couldn't find it when I was creating the app.

Comment: @BalaSivagnanam Hey there, I have been working on this and wanted to apply material theme and add a horizontal scroll using View Pager. If you have managed to customize it, I will be more than thankful if you could share your findings or guide me in the right direction.

Comment: @AhmadAliNasir no din't get time later to get this integrated into my app.

Comment: Be careful! There are several serious issues with 'android-collapse-calendar-view' library!